# How to click on a year in calendar with Selenium using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests

I am trying to write a Selenium test with JavaScript but was unable to fill calendar data. It is using a dropdown menu:

```
const {Builder, By, Key} = require('selenium-webdriver')


const test2 = async () => {

let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build()
await driver.manage().window().maximize()
await driver.get('https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form')
let calendar = 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='dateOfBirthInput']"))
await calendar.click()
let month = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='react- 
datepicker__month-select']"))
await month.click()
await month.sendKeys(Key.DOWN, Key.DOWN, Key.RETURN)

let year = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[contains(@class,'react-datepicker__year-select')]")).value = "1988"
```

How can I clcik on value that I need? Console logging year gives me 1988, but I don't know how to select it in the browser. Is there any other way besides pressing  Key.DOWN 35 times? I cannot use Select class in JavaScript.

Comment: can you provide a full code example that we can run with selenium installed in the coding environment?

Comment: I added builder and web page that leads to. Other code is not relevant i think as i am trying to verify that every input field is working correctly

Comment: @Vlmdr we cannot reproduce this without having the source code for the web page you are testing

Comment: I am sorry i didn't see that i didn't include that

Comment: No problem. If possible, please edit your question to free it of spelling errors, grammar, and include all resources needed to reproduce the issue. You can try to put it in a code sanbox env for us if possible and share the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the option tag to set values directly in the dropdown without opening it. Also, if your option is not found in the dropdown, an error will be thrown. You can handle it in a try block

```
month = "May"
year = "1988"
let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build()
await driver.manage().window().maximize()
await driver.get('https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form')
let calendar = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='dateOfBirthInput']"))
await calendar.click()
let month = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='react-datepicker__month-select']/option[text()='"+month+"']"))
await month.click()

let year = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[contains(@class,'react-datepicker__year-select')]/option[text()='"+year+"']"))
await year.click()
```

Comment: It's working. Thank you very much kind sir. You are a savior

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a *JavaScript* environment. However executing a javascript does the job.

Using Python clients:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#dateOfBirthInput")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", element, "24 Jan 2023")
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: DOB]

---

### Execution in the Console

Command

```
document.getElementById('dateOfBirthInput').value='24 Jan 2023'
```

Snapshot:

[image: console]